# $u(x):=\sum_{i: q_i\le x} 2^{-i}$ has no antiderivative.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and take an enumeration $(q_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then the function 
$$u(x):=\sum_{i: q_i\le x} 2^{-i} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} \mathbb{1}_{[q_i,1]}(x),\;\;x\in[0,1],$$ is increasing and satisfies $0\le u\le 1$, and its discontinuities are jumps at the points $q_i$ of height $u(q_i+)-u(q_i-)=2^{-i}$. Then $u$ is integrable, and since $(q_i)$ is dense, there is no interval $[c,d]\subset [0,1]$ such that $U'(x)=u(x)$ for all $x\in (c,d)$ for any function $U(x)$.

I don't understand the last sentence. Why does the fact that the point of discontinuities $q_i$ is dense imply that $u$ has no antiderivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function that's 0 for negative $x$, 1 for positive $x$. Given any interval containing zero, there's no function whose derivative is this function for all $x$ in the given interval.

More generally, if there's a jump discontinuity, there's no antiderivative over an interval containing that jump.

But every open interval contains a rational, hence, contains a jump of your function.